# check all code not working on Jquery 2.0

Tags: jquery

I am writing the following jquery code to select / unselect checkboxes. it works fine using jquery version 1.7.2 but failed while upgrading to jquery 2.0.*

Code:

```
$("#selectall").click(function () {
   $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

// if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox

```
$(".case").click(function(){
   if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
      $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
   } else {
      $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
   }
});
```

I also used this approach but it failed too.

```
$('#selectall').click(function() {
    $('.case').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked',!$(this).attr('checked'));
    });
});
```

Sample html output

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectall"> select all
.....
<input type="checkbox" class="case" value="1">
...
...
<input type="checkbox" class="case" value="5">
```

Note the following code failed on second attempt while checking / unchecking select all checkbox.

Comment: try with .prop instead of attr: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Try that jQuery Migrate plugin yet?

Comment: `checked` is a so called *boolean attribute*. No matter which value it has, its pure existence indicates that the element is checked. That's why you use `$("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");` in the second code example, but `$('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);` will simply set the value to `"false"` (if `this.checked` is `false`).

Comment: .prop worked thanks @RicardoE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Jquery.prop()` instead of `Jquery.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
$("#selectall").on('click', function () {
   $('.case').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Comment: There is no need to use `$(this).prop('checked')` over `this.checked`.